# How to recalculate inputted values for a new inputted value in Python?

Tags: python, indexing, recipe

```
print("For this recipe ", recipe[0], "for ", recipe[1])
print("You will need the following Ingredients with quantities and units: ")
Index = 2
while (Index != len(recipe)) :
    print(recipe[Index])
    Index = Index+1
    calculatedIQuantity = int(recipe[Index]) / int(recipe[1]) * int(peopleNo)
    print(calculatedIQuantity)
    Index = Index+1
    print(recipe[Index])
    Index = Index+1
```

The error is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\server\examuser41\test1.py", line 78, in <module>
    viewer()
  File "\\server\examuser41\test1.py", line 70, in viewer
    calculatedIQuantity = int(recipe[Index]) / int(recipe[1]) * int(peopleNo)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'cm\n'
>>>
```

How do I make it so my code recalculates the previous item quantities and units for the new number of people?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You `recipe` variable is a container which not carry all integer value, so when you use `typecasting` over your sequence then `casting` raises `literal error`
take a look:-

```
In [48]: int('12as2')
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12as2'
```

Comment: What would I do to fix it then?

Comment: @user3422851 what `type` actually your `recipe` is?

Comment: @user3422851 what is the data inside `recipe` and think if it's not carry real values or nombers how can you convert it to `integer.`

Comment: Well how do you use readlines to scan a txt file, then use these numbers to recalculate them for a different number of people?

Comment: @user3422851 it's a mathematics, you better describe the error in your code and apply logic.

Comment: @user3422851 if you find any help please mark correct the answer and pramote me on stackoverflow :-)